# Возможно ли работать с шаблоном асинхронно?

Tags: node.js, handlebars

Возникла необходимость работать с шаблоном Handlebars асинхронно. Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Зачем для шаблонов вообще асинхронность? Откуда у вас возникла необходимость? Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @andreymal, получаю данные из mongodb, он асинхронный, и вызывается несколько таких функций, а затем мне нужно запихнуть все в шаблон

Comment: Заранее асинхронно получите все данные и затем синхронно запихните в синхронный шаблон. Никакая асинхронная работа с шаблоном здесь не нужна

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, спасибо, попробую